# Change WAMP root directory for Apache so uses a shared folder from another virtual machine

Tags: apache, directory, wamp, document-root

I have installed Windows on a VMWare workstation and installed WAMP on it. Also I have installed WAMP on the main system. So I have shared `c:/wamp/www` folder from main system to that Virtual machine.

On virtual machine now I want to change root directory and set shared folder (`z:\www\`) as root.  Let's say my shared www folder for the Virtual machine is on path `z:\www\`. I have changed

```
DocumentRoot "z:/www/"
<Directory "z:/www/">
```

but it doesn't seem to work. WAMP won't start. What can I do?

Comment: When Apache won't start it almost always puts the reasons why into the error log.   Have you tried looking there?   What does it say?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic as it is not about webmastering as per http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic